# How would i wrap a 3d object around another 3d object which is beveled and round and a little bit square shaped?

Tags: objects, shrinkwrap, curve-modifier, surface-deform, lattice

[image: Reference]

I want to wrap the white and black mesh around the wood mesh(the blade), I have tried every way possible and it just does not work/it twists in weird ways or just does not twist/rotate at all. (things i have tried: path/curve/shrink-wrap/object deform/lattice), please help!

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21167/twist-rope-around-an-object/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/235744/how-to-properly-shrink-wrap-a-torus-looking-thing/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/235074/creating-diagonal-loop-cuts-in-a-cylinder https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/120946/how-to-make-straps-of-leather-wrapped-around-sword-handle/120950#120950

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lazy way to fake it would be to create one bandage that goes 360°, subdivide it and sculpt it a bit to create the folds:

[image]

Duplicate X times, rotate 180°, tilt it a bit with the *Shear* tool, move the UVs so that it doesn't show the same pattern:

[image]